# python variable m.start() from re.finditer does not get overwritten

Tags: python

I am currently writing a small python program for manipulating text files. (I am a newb programmer)

First, I am using re.finditer to find a specific string in lines1. Then I write this into a file and close it.
Next I want to grab the first line and search for this in another text file. The first time using re.finditer it was working great.

The problem is: m.start() always returns the last value of the first m.start. It does not get overwritten as it was the first time using re.finditer.

Could you help me understand why?

my code:

```
for m in re.finditer(finder1,lines1):
    end_of_line = lines1.find('\n',m.start())
    #print(m.start())
    found_tag = lines1[m.start()+lenfinder1:end_of_line]
    writefile.write(found_tag+'\n')
    lenfinder2 = len(found_tag)


input_file3 = open ('out.txt')
writefile.close()
num_of_lines3 = file_len('out.txt')

n=1
while (n < num_of_lines3):
    line = linecache.getline('out.txt', n)
    n = n+1
    re.finditer(line,lines2)
    #print(m.start())
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not declared\initialized `line` that you're using here :

```
re.finditer(line,lines2)
```

So, change :

```
linecache.getline('out.txt', n)
```

to

```
line = linecache.getline('out.txt', n)
```

Comment: sorry, I accidentally deleted "line ="  :( Its there in my code, but m.start does not work.

Comment: sorry i mean `m.start`, what do you get on printing `m.start`?

Comment: I got it now... I created two for loops, one with the existing m.start one with n.start. Now it works, I did not know it would bind to the counting variable